# MYSQL workbench & other IDEs not working on fresh OS after reinstall?

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I've recently had to format my computer and re-install my Win7 OS. Then I reinstalled the MySql workbench I was using last time. However, each time I open it and create a schema, the entire workbench crashes. I've tried rebooting, reinstalling, "check online for help" option, and even tried HeidiSQL which also starts but fails to connect to server. I've attached screenshots.

I think I might have to assume that this is a system fault and my system, since it is new, has some dependencies or some configuration that is missing. But both installations were fine so I'm not sure what those dependencies and configurations might be. Can someone offer some guidance on what can be done here? Thanks, greatly appreciated!!

[image]
[image]

I'm using 6.3.7 build 1199 CE (64 bit) Community.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by installing MySQL server. Recommend all to use MySQL installer web version which automatically lets you choose what packages you wish to install (this might even include something you wouldn't even install on your own), and it will download, install, and configure the latest versions of the packages on its own.

Thanks